# Why does the other symbols in the row change in my connect 4 game?

Tags: c++

Whenever it goes to the third row and onwards, the symbols from the 2nd row until the highest row in the column that is occupied will change to the same symbol as the highest row in the column that is occupied. Help!

I suspect the problem is the gravity() function in class BasePoint but I have no clue why it is working that way. I really need anybody's help please!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

class BasePoint
{
public:
  void setArray()
  {
    for (int x=0;x<6;x++)
    {
      for (int y=0; y<7; y++)
      {
        arry[x][y]=0;
      }
    }
  }

  void displayBoard()
  {
    cout<< "  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 "<< endl;
    for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
    {
      cout << "|";
      for (int y=0; y<7; y++)
      {
        if (arry[x][y]==0)
        {
          cout<< " *";
        }

        else if (arry[x][y]==1)
        {
          cout<< " X";
        }

        else if (arry[x][y]==2)
        {
          cout<< " O";
        }
      }
      cout << " |\n";
    }
  }

  void prompt(string player)
  {
    cout<< player << "'s turn. Enter a column number: ";
    cin>> dropChoice;
  }

  void gravity(int playr)
  {
    for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
    {
      if (arry[x][dropChoice-1]!=0)
      {
        if (playr==1)
        {
          arry[x-1][dropChoice-1]=1;
        }

        else if (playr==2)
        {
          arry[x-1][dropChoice-1]=2;
        }
      }
    }

    int count=0;
    for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
    {
      if (arry[x][dropChoice-1]==0)
      {
        count+=1;
      }
    }

    if (count==6)
    {
      if (playr==1)
      {
        arry[5][dropChoice-1]=1;
      }

      else if (playr==2)
      {
        arry[5][dropChoice-1]=2;
      }
    }
  }

  int checkWin(int plyr)
  {
    int result=0;

    for (int x=5; x>=0; x--)
    {
      for (int y=6; y>=0; y--)
      {
        if (arry[x][y]==plyr && arry[x-1][y-1]==plyr && arry[x-2][y-2]==plyr && arry[x-3][y-3]==plyr)
        {
          result=1;
        }

        else if (arry[x][y]==plyr && arry[x][y-1]==plyr && arry[x][y-2]==plyr && arry[x][y-3]==plyr)
        {
          result=1;
        }

        else if (arry[x][y]==plyr && arry[x-1][y]==plyr && arry[x-2][y]==plyr && arry[x-3][y]==plyr)
        {
          result=1;
        }

        else if (arry[x][y]==plyr && arry[x][y+1]==plyr && arry[x][y+2]==plyr && arry[x][y+3]==plyr)
        {
          result=1;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

private:
  int dropChoice;
  int arry[6][7];
};

class Point: public BasePoint
{
public:

  void readFile()
  {
    fstream read;

    read.open("account.txt");

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
      read >> name[x];
      read >> num[x];
    }

    read.close();
  }

  string getName(int a)
  {
    string namez;

    if (a==1)
    {
      namez=name[play1-1];
    }

    else if (a==2)
    {
      namez=name[play2-1];
    }

    return namez;
  }

  void accChoice()
  {
    cout<< "Accounts\tCredits" << endl;

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
     cout<< x+1 << ". " << name[x] << "\t" << num[x] << endl;
    }
    cout<< endl;

    cout<< "Player 1 account (1-5): ";
    cin>> play1;

    int flag=0;
    while (flag!=1)
    {
      cout<< "Player 2 account (1-5): ";
      cin>> play2;

      if (play2==play1)
      {
        cout<< "Sorry but this account has chosen. Choose again." << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        flag=1;
      }
    }
  }

private:
  string name[5];
  int num[5];
  int play1;
  int play2;
};

int main()
{
  Point thePoint;
  int stopper=0;
  thePoint.setArray();
  thePoint.readFile();
  thePoint.accChoice();
  string playr1=thePoint.getName(1);
  string playr2=thePoint.getName(2);

  while(stopper!=1)
  {
    thePoint.displayBoard();
    thePoint.prompt(playr1);
    thePoint.gravity(1);
    thePoint.displayBoard();
    int final=thePoint.checkWin(1);

    if (final==0)
    {
      thePoint.prompt(playr2);
      thePoint.gravity(2);
      final=thePoint.checkWin(2);

      if (final==1)
      {
        stopper=1;
        cout<< "Congratulations! " << playr2 << " has won the game!" << endl;
      }

    }

    else if (final==1)
    {
      stopper=1;
      cout<< "Congratulations! " << playr1 << " has won the game!" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are a few place where you might access the array out-of-bounds. For example: `arry[x-1]` when `x = 0`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the user will input 1-7 so it wouldn't go out of bounds there and as for the rows, it will check until the row that is occupied. It will then -1 to put it into the point higher than it.

Comment: *the user will input 1-7 so it wouldn't go out of bounds there*  -- We cannot duplicate your error, as it relies on specific input being done.

Comment: `for (int x=0; x<6; x++)` in `gravity()` will set every space in that column to whatever player you are given. You need to figure out how to change only the bottom.